# How can I determine that BootstrapVue has also included the JavaScript files required by Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-vue

I'm setting up BootstrapVue in my project, and the CSS appears to be there, but I'm not sure how I can confirm that the JavaScript files are included.

In the bootstrap getting started guide, it says to include this JavaScript file:

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

How can I confirm that it's getting included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BootstrapVue does not use any of Bootstrap's javascript files. BootstrapVue has re-implemented their jQuery code using Vue (no jQuery required)

So there is no need to include Bootstrap's javascript file in your project.